# How to display two texts in a single EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want two different texts should appear in a single EditText.

[image: toBeAchieved]

I tried like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="+91"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:theme="@style/Regestration_edit_text"
        android:id="@+id/rhs_country_code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:theme="@style/Regestration_edit_text"
        android:id="@+id/rhs_mobile_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: results]

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: you can concat both the string and display it.

Comment: `editText.setText("+91   " + mobileNumber);`

Comment: thank you @MuhammadBabar

Comment: but Mobile Number is a hint text. and +91 is uneditable text.

Answer (score 1):

Heres your layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_line_edit_text"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rhs_country_code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="+91"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/rhs_mobile_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="Mobile Number"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is you drawable (bg_line_edit_text)

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@android:color/black"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```